# how to download hidden dot-directories with lftp's mirror command

Tags: linux, lftp

I don't know how to download hidden dot-directories with lftp's mirror command

I just can get a dot-file with get command, and list the hide files with ls -a command for now.

Can this be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp

```
   ftp:list-options (string)
          sets options which are always appended to LIST command. 
          It can be useful to set this to `-a' if server does not
          show dot (hidden) files by default.  Default is empty.
```

Answer (score 4):

lftp -u username,password hostname.com -e "set ftp:list-options -a"

mirror